# Android Studio - How can I let Switch be checked after restarting the app

Tags: android, sdk, switch-statement

I only have a switch toggle on my fragment.
What is the app doing now: The user opens the app and selects "Laptop" over the navigation drawer and then he sees a switch (it is a "slider" which you can move to on or off...hope you understand what I mean). The user sets switch to ON then closes the app and reopens it and the switch is off...but it shouldn't be off...it should be on, like the user sets it
How can I do that? The switch should save its state, how the user selects it
Do I need mysql or something?

I hope you understand what I mean

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use SharedPreferences like so:

```
 public static final String SWITCH_PREFS = "Switcher";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        Switch switcher = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.yourSwitchId);
        switcher.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(yourContext).edit();
                editor.putBoolean(SWITCH_PREFS,isChecked);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(yourContext);
        if(prefs.contains(SWITCH_PREFS) && switcher != null)
        {
            switcher.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(SWITCH_PREFS,false));
        }

    }
```

Didn't try this code, but hope this works.

Comment: I tried this, but he is giving me an error on `findViewById`
This is the Error: `cannot resolve method findViewById(int)`
I have also googled this error, but I don't find any solution. Hope you can help.

And second question. What should I write as `yourContext`? Thanks

Comment: well, you have layout where you put your Switch. You have to add android:id="@+id/switch_id" attribute to the xml Switch item. Then you can find this using findViewById. the code I described above you should put to your Activity code. If you put this code in your Activity class then just use **this** instead of **yourContext**.

Comment: my Switch has an id. Is it maybe, because the switch is on a fragment? I am extending Fragment, if this information helps

Comment: Then you should move all this code to your OnCreateView method.

Comment: and to get the Switch instance use -         `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, false);
        Switch switcher = view.findViewById();`

Comment: thanks. But know he is giving me an error on the code `getDefaultSharedPreferenced(this)` on `this` The error: He cannot apply PreferenceManager to com.example.dev.LaptopFragment

Comment: you should retrieve Context or Activity. use getActivity instead of this.

Comment: thank you very much but there is still the same issue

Comment: what issue? please update your question or create a new one and send me a link to it.

Comment: It is still the same issue. But i will create a new question and send you the link. thank your for your help!

Comment: i will delete this question
This is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910518/how-to-save-the-state-of-an-fragment-in-android

Comment: Mark my answer as answer if it is helpful. And the question will close.

Comment: thanks man!! but can you plz explain me what you are doing in `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and what after that? i want to unterstand

Comment: this - onCheckedChanged(..) invokes when user change state of the switcher(from ON to OFF or vice versa) Then the state saves to Preferences(persistant storage to save user data). and after user enter the app, by doing this - you retrieve and set the previous state of the switcher. switcher.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(SWITCH_PREFS,false));